# Flash AS3 fisheye

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, fisheye

I was hoping someone here could point me in the direction of a good Flash AS3 fisheye application. I need something that can have the images in the fisheye but be able to scroll as you get closer to the right/left sides of the container because the images are going to overflow the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a panorama viewer. I've never used any, but I've heard good things about http://krpano.com/